# Sample size determination contradiction

Tags: binomial-distribution, sample-size

I'm struggling with a contradiction when trying to determine a sample size when proportion is small. If I use binomial formula:
 $n = p(1-p)z^2/ME^2$
then the smaller the proportion - the smaller sample size I need. The maximum sample size is actually at $p = 0.5$
However, I've often seen following rule of thumb for ([normal approximation to binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation)):
$np > 10$ AND $n(1-p) > 10$
which works opposite - the smaller $p$ is, the larger sample size I need. 
Which kind of makes sense intuitively: if the chance is 1 in 1000, I better test at least 1000, especially if it is a critical issue.

In summary, the first formula says the smaller $p$ is - the smaller sample size I need. The second approach, conversely, says that the smaller $p$ is - the larger sample size I need. Which one is right? Can I use the binomial for determining the sample size when proportion is small (which also raises a question how small is small)? And if not - why?

Thank you!

Comment: Please tell us to what procedure that rule of thumb applies. Observe, too, the change in your approach between the beginning and end of the question: the first part concerns estimating a proportion *plus or minus* some specified error ("ME" presumably) but the last part argues for estimating a proportion up to some *relative amount* of that proportion. There can no possibility of real controversy unless you adopt a consistent objective for your sampling program.

Comment: I see no controversy there at all. No hint of contradiction.  The "rule of thumb" is apparently not doing what you seem to think it's doing. Look it up. What's it *for*? It's true that the standard errors of small proportions are smaller than proportions near 0.5 at the same $n$. Note that the sample size formula uses a normal approximation, so if the normal is a poor approximation, it may not give suitable answers.

Comment: @whuber : Thank you for your response. I agree that there should be no real controversy here, but I'm still confused. The rule of thumb applies to using the normal approximation for the binomial distribution: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) . Basically, I have a very small $p = 0.004$ and I need to decide which approach to use for determining the sample size. The first formula says the smaller $p$ is - the smaller sample size I need. The second approach, conversely, says that the smaller $p$ is - the larger sample size I need. Which one is right?

Comment: You will likely get more appropriate (and better) answers by editing your question to focus on what you really need to know, as explained in that last comment.

Comment: @whuber and Glen_b : thank you, I have edited the question. Hopefully it is more clear now.