# Determining Sample Size When Low Probability Items Are Of Interest

Tags: confidence-interval, sample, survey-sampling

Let's assume there are 10,000,000 Yankee fans and we want to analyze what else these 10 million people are fans of. A  simple question is, what sample size do we need to be confident in the results?

Using this formula, we want a 95% conf interval, corresponding to z of 1.96 with ME of .02. We set p to the max it can give, which is p = 0.5.

=(1−)^2/^2 = 0.5 * 0.5 * 1.96^2/.02^2 = 2,401

The results look like the below table. Please note, the results don't add up to 100% since each person sampled can be a fan of multiple things.

```
Subject     % of sample that is a fan of subject
Derek Jeter      40% 
Babe Ruth    37% 
MLB      35% 
New York Knicks      30% 
New York Giants      10% 
Al Pacino     8% 
Ultimate Fighting Championship    8% 
Goodfellas (movie)    7% 
Paris Hilton      5% 
Amazon    3%
```

The fact that 40% of Yankee fans like Derek Jeter is not much of a surprise since he is such a well-liked member of the team. However, it is interesting to see Al Pacino at 8%.

The questions I have are:

- How confident can we be that if we were to pull another sample of 2,401 people that Al Pacino would be at 8%? Said differently, what is the confidence interval around 8%?
- What is the probability that he doesn't show up in the results at all?
- Is there a percentage that is too low to be reliable? For example, "data science" may show up at 1%. Is that number reliable, or should there be a threshold percentage that needs to be reported before we deem it reliable?

I am asking this question because the sample size formula confuses me. In this case, I am more interested in items that have a lesser likelihood of showing up, but the formula would suggest a smaller size. This is non-intutive. The smaller the sample I take, the more likely a spurious result could show up. This is discussed in this question, [Sample size determination contradiction](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93924/sample-size-determination-contradiction)

Thank you.

Comment: The answer to the first bullet is not a confidence interval: it's a prediction interval.  The third bullet is too vaguely formulated to be answerable, because it depends on whatever you might mean by "reliable."  The sample size formula you quote is an approximation that relies on assuming a near-Normal sampling distribution of the proportion.  For proportions very close to $0$ or $1,$ where the total number of  less-popular responses is less than 10 or so, that assumption is woefully incorrect.